# Setting Azure Functions Runtime Version for local dev with Visual Studio 2017

Tags: azure, azure-functions

AF runtime 2.0.12332 was working locally with VS 2017. But it is automatically changed to 2.0.12353, which has [issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55174543/depdency-injection-and-logging-start-failing-suddently-without-code-changes-when).

How can I change to 2.0.12332 or other version that supports DI via ctor on local station?

[image]

[image]
Possible solutions if possible, but how can I achieve it?

1) support different versions locally and run specific version, or

2) un-install current version, and re-install corect version

**Update**

Exception caused by the lack of IoC support:

```
2019-03-15T01:28:45.311 [Error] Executed 'Test' (Failed, Id=6bdb0e8e-2353-4ed2-83ce-2a5288fd124d)
System.InvalidOperationException : Unable to resolve service for type 'ICar' while attempting to activate 'TestFunctions'.
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.GetService(IServiceProvider sp,Type type,Type requiredBy,Boolean isDefaultParameterRequired)
   at lambda_method(Closure ,IServiceProvider ,Object[] )
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.DefaultJobActivator.CreateInstance[T](IServiceProvider serviceProvider) at C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\DefaultJobActivator.cs : 42
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.DefaultJobActivator.CreateInstance[T](IFunctionInstanceEx functionInstance) at C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\DefaultJobActivator.cs : 32
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.ActivatorInstanceFactory`1.<>c__DisplayClass1_1.<.ctor>b__0(IFunctionInstanceEx i) at C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\ActivatorInstanceFactory.cs : 20
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.ActivatorInstanceFactory`1.Create(IFunctionInstanceEx functionInstance) at C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\ActivatorInstanceFactory.cs : 26
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionInvoker`2.CreateInstance(IFunctionInstanceEx functionInstance) at C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\FunctionInvoker.cs : 44
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor.ParameterHelper.Initialize() at C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\FunctionExecutor.cs : 845
   at async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor.TryExecuteAsyncCore(IFunctionInstanceEx functionInstance,CancellationToken cancellationToken) at C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\FunctionExecutor.cs : 116
```

To fix the runtime issue on Azure Functions, see [Depdency Injection and Logging start failing suddently without code changes when they were working properly with Azure Functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55174543/depdency-injection-and-logging-start-failing-suddently-without-code-changes-when?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To fix the runtime issue on Azure Functions, see [Depdency Injection and Logging start failing suddently without code changes when they were working properly with Azure Functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55174543/depdency-injection-and-logging-start-failing-suddently-without-code-changes-when/55199041?noredirect=1#comment97427812_55199041)

**Solution 1**

1 download this
https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-core-tools/releases/tag/2.4.419

2 Replace files from step 1 to below

```
%AppData%\..\Local\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases\2.18.4\cli
```

`2.18.4` might be different from your current folder. Check this to see your current folder

[image]

**[Soluton 2](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-core-tools/wiki/%5BV1%5D-Running-64bit-functions-in-Visual-Studio)**

1 Download and extract the latest x64 1.x release from here https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-core-tools/releases

2 Right click on your project Properties -> Debug

3 Change Launch to Executable, and put the path for the downloaded x64 func.exe

4 set Application arguments to host start

5 F5

[image]