# Azure function runtime 3.3.1 cannot be chosen

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-functions-runtime

when we set the FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION to either 3.3.1 or 3.3.0 it still selects 3.2.0, so it seems that 3.3.1 is still not available to us even though it is on the [release page](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/releases)?

Anybody know what could be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [MS DOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/set-runtime-version?tabs=portal)

> If you specify a minor version (for example, "2.0.12345"), the
> function app is pinned to that specific version until you explicitly
> change it. Older minor versions are regularly removed from the
> production environment. If your minor version gets removed, your
> function app goes back to running on the latest version instead of the
> version set in `FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION`. As such, you should
> quickly resolve any issues with your function app that require a
> specific minor version. Then, you can return to targeting the major
> version. Minor version removals are announced in [App Service
> announcements](https://github.com/Azure/app-service-announcements/issues).

For more information please refer this [SO THREAD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55360358/setting-azure-functions-runtime-version-for-local-dev-with-visual-studio-2017) .

Comment: Don't understand your comment. 3.3.1 is the newest release and has just been announced. See my link. So why should it not be available anymore?